# rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `misc_info'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Rake version : 12.0.0
Ruby : ruby 2.3.0
Rails : Rails 4.2.0

A ruby app when run below rake db:reset gives undefined method error.

Below rake commands are not giving any issue.

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate 

rake db:schema

rake db:seed
```

But when I run rake db:reset, it gives below error

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `misc_info' for #<Venue:0x007ff593140ee8> Did you mean?  misc_info_raw
```

> seeds.rb is as below.

```
User .create!([{ first_name: "abc", last_name: "abcd", :email => "ancd@gmail.com", :password => "password", role: 2}]) `

 TimeZone.create([
  { :name => "US/Pacific", :created_at => "2013-06-06 22:14:08", :updated_at => "2013-07-09 18:55:41" },
  { :name => "US/Arizona", :created_at => "2014-09-17 03:05:58", :updated_at => "2015-02-02 18:24:38" },
  { :name => "US/Mountain", :created_at => "2013-06-09 22:54:23", :updated_at => "2015-02-02 18:24:49" },
  { :name => "US/Eastern", :created_at => "2013-06-07 00:22:41", :updated_at => "2015-02-02 18:24:57" }
  ], :without_protection => true )

  time_zone = TimeZone.find_by_name("US/Pacific")

   Subdivision.create!([
    { :locale1 => "PQDS",
      :locale2 => "abcd",
      :locale3 => "abcd",
      :locale_code => "CA",
      :postal_code => "90210",
      :country => "United States",
      :country_code => "US",
      :latitude => 34.1030032,
      :longitude => -118.4104684,
      :time_zone_id => time_zone.id,
      :created_at => "2013-12-17 20:23:52",
      :updated_at => "2014-10-02 21:53:06",
      :is_visible => true,
      :uber_enabled => true }
      ], :without_protection => true )`

      subdivision = Subdivision.find_by_locale3("abcd")

      venue = Venue.new({
        name: "XXXX",
        club_type: 1,
        address: "XXX XXXX, XXX, CA",
        average_per_bottle: nil,
        thumbnail_photo_id: nil,
        phone_number: "5554443333",
        bt_cut: 25,
        music_description: "dsd",
        crowd_description: "fffdf",
        email: "fdfsf@gmail.com",
        braintree_merchant_id: nil,
        braintree_verified: false,
        score: 0,
        active_venue:true,
        about: "this place is great",
        percent_discount: 0,
        subdivision_id: subdivision.id
        })

        venue.save!

        # Create a venue with an initial table section.
        # section_image_path = "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/dasda.jpeg"
        section = Section.new(
        location: "Pool Section",
        variety: 1,
        capacity: 12
        )
        section.venue = venue

        schedule = section.build_schedule
        schedule.time = Time.now.utc
        schedule.date = Time.now.utc
        schedule.rule = "weekly"
        schedule.day = ['monday', 'wednesday', 'friday', 'saturday']
        section.minimums = {sunday: 5000, monday: 3000, tuesday: 1400, wednesday: 2000, thursday: 3400, friday: 3000, saturday: 4000}
        schedule.save!
        section.save!
```

Any help would be appreciated

Full error trace :

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `misc_info' for #<Venue:0x007f82eb2c88d0>
Did you mean?  misc_info_raw
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:149:in `block in validate'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `each'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `validate'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:450:in `public_send'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:450:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:189:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:395:in `run_validations!'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `block in run_validations!'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:219:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.0/lib/active_model/validations.rb:334:in `valid?'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:58:in `valid?'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:83:in `perform_validations'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/workspace/pk-workspace/pcp-Admin/db/seeds.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:216:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `each'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:139:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
```

Adding models/venue.rb

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  nilify_blanks
  attr_accessor   :misc_info_raw

  def misc_info_raw
    self.misc_info.join("\n, ") unless self.misc_info.nil?
  end

  def misc_info_raw=(values)
    self.misc_info = []
    self.misc_info = values
  end
  # Geocoding
  geocoded_by :full_address do |venue, results|
    if geo = results.first
      venue.latitude = geo.latitude
      venue.longitude = geo.longitude
      venue.district = geo.neighborhood if geo.neighborhood
    end
  end

  after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?

  CLUB_TYPES = [nil, ‘xxx’, ‘xxxx’, ‘xxxx’,
    ‘Xx’, ‘xx xxxx’, ‘xxx xxx’]

    belongs_to :subdivision
    has_many :events
    has_many :stake_holders
    has_one :thumbnail_image
    has_many :inventories, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :promotions
    has_many :claimed_promotions

    has_many :reviews
    has_many :images, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :sections, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subdivision,
    :images, :inventories,
    :thumbnail_image, :sections, :allow_destroy => true

    validates :name,
    :presence => true,
    :length => { :maximum => 30 }

    validates :misc_info, :about,
    :length => { :maximum => 255 }

    validates :club_type,
    :about,
    :percent_discount,
    :bt_cut,
    :district,
    :email, :presence => true

    #cell_image is used instead of thumbnail_image for versions < 2.0
    has_attached_file :cell_image,
    :url => "/thumbnails/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :path => "/thumbnails/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

    validates_attachment_content_type :cell_image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

    # Required for geocoding
    def full_address
      address
    end

    def first_image_url
      self.images.empty? ? nil : self.images.first.image_url
    end

    def thumb_image_url
      self.cell_image.url if self.cell_image
    end

    def small_thumb_image_url
      self.thumbnail_image.image.url if self.thumbnail_image
    end

    DESC_HTML_BEG = "<div style=\"font-family:helvetica;color:white;\" >\r\n<p>\r\nDetails\r\n</p>\r\n<hr>\r\n<div>\r\n<ul>\r\n"
    DESC_HTML_END = "\r\n</div>\r\n</div>"

    #don't return quote if it is not a day of request
    def description(days_in_future)
      base = "#{description_1}#{description4}#{description2}#{description3}"
      base = "#{self.special_event_html}#{base}" unless self.tonights_event.nil? if days_in_future == 0
      base = "#{self.bt_offer_html}#{base}" unless self.bt_offer.nil?

      "#{DESC_HTML_BEG}#{base}#{DESC_HTML_END}"
    end

    def special_event_html
      return_li_html("SPECIAL EVENT: #{self.tonights_event}")
    end

    def bt_offer_html
      return_li_html("BT EXCLUSIVE OFFER: Free #{self.bt_offer.inventory.master_inventory.brand} #{ self.bt_offer.inventory.master_inventory.name } with every order!")
    end

    #returns string wrapped in li html style
    def return_li_html(s)
      "<li style=\"padding-bottom:1ex\">#{s}</li>"
    end

    def merchant_cut
      ((100 - self.bt_cut) * 0.01).to_f
    end

    def discount
      (self.percent_discount * 0.01).to_f
    end

    #returns club type string based off database int column club_type
    def club_type_string
      CLUB_TYPES[self.club_type]
    end

    #returns club types
    def self.club_types
      CLUB_TYPES
    end

    def get_bt_merchant_id
      "#{ name.gsub(/[^0-9a-z\\s]/i, '').downcase }_#{ self.subdivision.locale_code }_#{ self.subdivision.postal_code }"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please provide full trace of error. I suppose it's about some dependencies in your `Venue` model such as callbacks.

Comment: do `rake db:reset --trace` to get full trace.

Comment: @DjezzzL is right, the problem in validation callbacks.

Comment: Do you have `misc_info` attribute in `venues` table?

Comment: @Pavan yup misc_info was missing in `venues` table. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tushR Please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `misc_info' for
>   Venue:0x007ff593140ee8 Did you mean?  misc_info_raw

As I said, you are missing `misc_info` column in your `venues` table. Adding it back should solve the problem.